# Export svn dump to git or github

Tags: git, github, svn

I have a svn dump (but the actual svn website is no longer active). Is there a way to upload this dump to git or github? The tutorials that I see pertain to using svn-git and need access to the actual svn website.

Comment: At worse, you can import your SVN dump into an SVN repo, and then use git-svn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You can extract the dump and convert it to git even without a server:

```
svnadmin create /home/user/svn/repo
svnadmin load /home/user/svn/repo < svndump.dat
git svn clone file:///home/user/svn/repo /home/user/svn/repo.git
```

2) [reposurgeon](http://www.catb.org/~esr/reposurgeon/) can migrate svn dump directly, without extracting it.

Answer (score 3):

[svndump-to-git](https://svndump-to-git.github.io) can be used as an alternative to reposurgeon in this case so long as the subversion dump is in version 2 format.

It is a whole repository converter with automatic branch detection.